# WireMockRule does not work for non local host in integration test

Tags: java, spring, wiremock, integration-testing

I'm trying to mock request for remote host using *WireMockRule* and I'm stucked. Currently I'm mocking request for local host like below:

```
  @Rule
  public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(80);

  ...

  wireMockRule.stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo("/api/users"))
   .willReturn(aResponse()
   .withStatus(200)));
```

and these works properly for localhost. However when I try to do analogically

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule(wireMockConfig().bindAddress("remote").port(80));
```

it doesny work, event test doesnt start. So I would like to ask you guys, maybe anybody would know what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`WireMockRule` always starts a server on localhost. It is not designed for connecting to a remote WireMock server. You can see this from its source.

To configure the WireMock client to run against a remote server, don't use `@Rule`. Just put `WireMock.configureFor("my.remote.host", 8000);` in the constructor in the initialisation of your test.

Typically, whether you're using the `@Rule` or not, the designer of WireMock expects you to use the static methods on the `WireMock` class, rather than the member methods of `WireMockRule` object:

```
 import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;

 ...

 stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo("/api/users"))
   .willReturn(aResponse()
       .withStatus(200)));
```

Comment: But I need to mock request to not existing host (when I'm running Integration tests host is offline).. Is it even possible?

Comment: If you want to start a WireMock server on a remote host, you'll have to do so yourself. There's nothing provided by WireMock that launches a server on a remote host for you.